# What's the generic name of the magnetic rulers of Xcode and do you have tips to implement them ?

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement a magnetic ruler feature like the Interface Builder uses to align objects, the dotted blue lines in the following example:

[image: Example]

First: what is the name of this kind of feature that I can search and will not end on compass discussion.

And then: do you know some library or components that would help ?

I already successfully implemented [spuserresizableview](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/spuserresizableview) 
to move and resize my components, but I would like to align them.

Comment: The name of the feature is often called Snapping, because items will snap to the lines that it draws.

Comment: Thanks ! It's really easier to find something when you know the correct word.
Anyway, it doesn't look like there is lot of implementations of this but I found some discussions that will surely help